# How to initiate PPTP MSCHAP authentication in java?

Tags: android, vpn, pptp

I'm trying to implement a PPTP android client in java for a customer.

The authentication is to be done via `MSCHAP-v2` (Security not a concern at this level).

My initial idea was that:
if: I send a `Start-Ctrl-Connection-Request` to the server (via the default port 1723),
-> it will reply with a `Start-Ctrl-Connection-Reply` followed by the `16-byte` authentication challenge.

I'm able to read a `156-byte` `Start-Ctrl-Connection-Reply` as expected **but** there's no `16-byte` challenge followed.

Now it seems to me that I have to request for the challenge in some other way than sending `control-connections`.

> Any idea on
>   1- How to request for the auth-challenge? Even the RFC regarding `MS-CHAP` does not give any clue on this.
>   2- Or am I missing something?